# Disable a check in a file when using Python futurize

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pylint

I'm running periodically `futurize -stage1` to validate changes in my project. There is a class defining a has_key method that flags the has_key fixer. Is it there a way to disable a check in a line or in a file?
Something similar to `# pylint: disable=...` that can be added in a file or inline with a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the features requested seems to be available there at the moment.

What you can do is

1. disable a specific fixer with `-x <fixer specification>`
2. run futurize with a list of files to convert, to avoid processing a specific file
3. run futurize as usual and revert/ignore changes from files/places you don't care about

Solutions 2 and 3 would require some scripting and I can imagine ignoring changes at the line level using something like `# futurize: ignore`

Comment: Thanks, @smido. In the end, I used a mix of 3, when running futurize to help w/ the conversion, and ignoring the errors or 2 when using futurize as CI test to verify the compliance of new code changes. Now it is all Python 3 and this is behind